# How to update column name with respect to another column data in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

i have a requirement as below

df

```
+-------------+----+------+--------+----+
|          des|  id|veh_cd|veh_p_cd|code|
+-------------+----+------+--------+----+
|BodilyInjured|1001|    45|      50| BI_|
|BodilyInjured|1001|    12|      55| BI_|
|    Collision|1001|    18|      21|col_|
|    Collision|1002|    21|      25|col_|
+-------------+----+------+--------+----+
```

if the "des" is "BodilyInjured" then two separate column should be added "BI_veh_cd" for "veh_cd" and BI_veh_p_cd for "veh_p_cd" which should contain max values of veh_cd and veh_p_cd and the same goes for "Collision"

Note: Need to append respective "code" to "veh_cd" and "veh_p_cd" for column names and respective data should be populated. column name format should be code+columnname. ex: for BodilyInjured code is BI now column name should be "BI_veh_cd" and "BI_veh_p_cd"

expected output

```
id  BI_veh_cd   BI_veh_p_cd     col_veh_cd  col_veh_p_cd
1001    45        55            18            21
1002    NULL      NULL         21             25
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162324/discussion-between-luzo-and-mtoto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the pivot functionality:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

df1 = df.groupBy("id") \
       .pivot("code") \
       .agg(max("veh_cd"), max("veh_p_cd")) \
       .orderBy("id")
```

To rename your columns we can use vanilla `Python` regex:

```
import re

newnames = [re.sub("max|\(|\)", '', i) for i in df1.columns]
df1.toDF(*newnames).show()
+----+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  id|BI__veh_cd|BI__veh_p_cd|col__veh_cd|col__veh_p_cd|
+----+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|1001|        45|          55|         18|           21|
|1002|      null|        null|         21|           25|
+----+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```